# How can I fix the back navigation with fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem implementing the back navigation.

Activity `A1` starts Activity `A2`. `A2` contains a full screen fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- fragment goes here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

in `A2`'s `onCreate()` I load the fragment F1 in the container above:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    replaceFragment(new AccountHomeFragment());
}

public void replaceFragment(Fragment f){
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f);
     fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(f.getClass().getSimpleName());
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

And at some point the user clicks on a button and the `F1` is replaced by `F2`. **The problem is when the user clicks on the back button:**

- 1st click: nothing happens
- 2nd click: goes from `F2` to `A1` (`F1` skipped)

What I expect

- 1st click: `F2`->`F1`
- 2nd click: `F1`->`A1`

I have noticed that if I press back before F1 is replaced by F2:

- 1st click: `F1`->blank screen
- 2nd click: blank screen->`A1`

Comment: On what you expect, you meant F2->F1 then F1->A1, right?

Comment: @dmon: Absolutely. I corrected the question.

Comment: How do you add F2? Do you use the replaceFragment method?

Comment: @dmon: yes, i call replaceFragment(new F2());

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be caused by adding your first fragment to the backstack as well. In your `onCreate` you call `replaceFragment` which adds it automatically. Just add the fragment manually without the `addToBackStack` call and use the `replaceFragment` function for all subsequent fragment transactions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that but then when I click back in F2 I skip A2-F1 and go directly back to A1